# Ajax Bringing in a div and turning it into a slider

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have used Ajax to load a div with `id` of `slider`.

I want to use the jquery statement `$('#slider').orbit();`

Since this is loaded via Ajax, I am not sure how to do this. In the past, I have used the `on` function when I have had to add click events. However, since this just needs to run without any `click`, `hover` etc. I am not sure how to do it?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing a jQuery AJAX call you can (and usually should) specify a `success` function, which runs when a successful response from the server is received. Simply execute your code inside of that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(response) {
        // some code
        $('#slider').orbit();
    }
});
```

If you're using one of the shorthand jQuery functions - such as `$.get()` or `$.post()` - then the success function is passed as one of its parameters:

```
$.post(url, function(response) {
    // some code
    $('#slider').orbit();
});
```

Related docs:

- [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Thanks - annoyingly I was using this format before, but inbetween I learnt the on function, and completely lost the plot. This of course works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Use the ajax callback function to run that code.

You can find the syntax in the relevant function in the JQuery api.

http://api.jquery.com